# How to merge partial data into a given df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How can I merge partial data into a given df, without changing unknown values? Here is a minimal example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = {
...     "Feat_A": ["INVALID", "INVALID", "INVALID"],
...     "Feat_B": ["INVALID", "INVALID", "INVALID"],
...     "Key": [12, 25, 99],
... }
>>> 
>>> origin = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
>>> data = {"Feat_A": [1, np.nan], "Feat_B": [np.nan, 2], "Key": [12, 99]}
>>> new = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
>>> origin = origin.merge(
...     new[["Key", "Feat_A", "Feat_B"]],
...     on="Key",
...     how="left",
... )
>>> 
>>> origin
  Feat_A_x Feat_B_x  Key  Feat_A_y  Feat_B_y
0  INVALID  INVALID   12       1.0       NaN
1  INVALID  INVALID   25       NaN       NaN
2  INVALID  INVALID   99       NaN       2.0
```

This is what I am looking for:

```
#    Feat_A   Feat_B    Key  
# 0  1.0      INVALID   12
# 1  INVALID  INVALID   25   
# 2  INVALID  2.0       99
```

Comment: isnt `pd.concat()` better in this scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found pretty solution here: [Overwrite columns in DataFrames of different sizes pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42544918/overwrite-columns-in-dataframes-of-different-sizes-pandas)

```
df_result = df2.set_index('ids').combine_first(df1.set_index('ids'))
df_result.reset_index()
```

Furthermore, df.update() seems to do something like that, but I did not figure out how to take care of different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

First set "INVALID" cells to NAN then you can set `key` as index and use fillna method to fill the values from new to origin.

```
import numpy as np
origin = origin.map({'INVALID':np.nan})
originNew=origin.set_index('Key').fillna(new.set_index("Key"))
```